Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' - swagger
I have included swagger in express and deployed on vercel. Swagger is working fine locaally but giving Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in browser console when i deploy app to vercel. Given below is my configuration for swagger
//swaggerJsDoc
const options = {
  definition: {
    openapi: "3.0.0",
    info: {
      title: "Medical Products E-Commerce API",
      version: "1.0.0",
      description: "API for Medical Products and User Authentication",
    },

    servers: [
      {
        url: "https://mpeb-delta.vercel.app",
        description: "Production",
      },
    ],
  },
  explorer: true,
  apis: ["./swagger/swagger-docs.js"],
};

const specs = swaggerJsDoc(options);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(specs));


